# Jenkins pipeline mvn: command not found

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My test is working fine as Maven project. It fetches code from Git.

I wanted to execute the same in Pipeline so I wrote the below script for pipeline project.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    stages{ 
        stage('Just Testing') {
            steps {
                git "https://github.com/myRepo.git"
                script{
                        sh 'mvn test'
                }
                step([$class : 'Publisher', reportFilenamePattern : "**/testng-results.xml"])
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

But when I execute I am getting mvn: command not found error Java and Maven path is set correctly in global tool configuration (I am sure because I am able to execute other maven projects, only pipeline is failing.)

Console output:

```
Running on Jenkins in /Users/abacker/.jenkins/workspace/parallelTestNG
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Just Testing)
[Pipeline] git
00:03:52  No credentials specified
00:03:52   > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
00:03:52  Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
00:03:52   > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/myRepo.git # timeout=10
00:03:52  Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/myRepo.git
00:03:52   > git --version # timeout=10
00:03:52   > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/myRepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
00:03:54   > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
00:03:54   > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
00:03:54  Checking out Revision e82f48106aa72d0275591926d9cd3226ba0fefd7 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
00:03:54   > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
00:03:54   > git checkout -f e82f48106aa72d0275591926d9cd3226ba0fefd7 # timeout=10
00:03:54   > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
00:03:54   > git branch -D master # timeout=10
00:03:54   > git checkout -b master e82f48106aa72d0275591926d9cd3226ba0fefd7 # timeout=10
00:03:54  Commit message: "First commit"
00:03:54   > git rev-list --no-walk e82f48106aa72d0275591926d9cd3226ba0fefd7 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
00:03:54  + mvn test
00:03:54  /Users/abacker/.jenkins/workspace/parallelTestNG@tmp/durable-818e64a8/script.sh: line 1: mvn: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have any tools declared for your maven project.

[image]

This would be a good starting point for running mvn goals from Jenkins.
[Declarative maven project](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/).

Comment: This worked, thank you. Added  
tools { 
        maven 'M2_HOME' 
        jdk 'JAVA_HOME' 
    }
Set the path in Global Tools Configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Following pipeline script did the job for me. unlike maven projects created in jenkins you need to add the maven and java as tool for the script.
MAVEN_HOME - configured in "Managing Jenkins" → "Global Tool Configuration"
JAVA_HOME - configured in "Managing Jenkins" → "Global Tool Configuration"

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools { 
      maven 'MAVEN_HOME' 
      jdk 'JAVA_HOME' 
    }
    stages {
      stage ('Build') {
        steps {
          sh 'mvn -B -ntp -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore verify'
        }
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the pipeline script you have to give maven path like

```
def mvnHome = tool name: 'maven-3.8.6', type: 'maven'
                    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn package"
```

in maven stage

I hope it will work because it works for me.. thank you